# Redirect 301 Urls with id number htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, prestashop, redirect

I have urls like this

```
https://www.example.co.uk/382-princeton-teak-6ft-garden-bench-chinoiserie-bench.html
```

That i want to redirect to

```
https://www.example.co.uk/princeton-teak-6ft-garden-bench-chinoiserie-bench.html
```

I tried with `RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.+?)([0-9]+)-(.*)\.html$ /$1.html` it do match but it redirects to `https://www.example.co.uk/3.html` any thoughts guys ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using this rule as number is right at the start:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/[0-9]+-(.+\.html)$ /$1
```

Clear your browser cache to test this change.

Comment: for some reason it redirects to https://www.example.co.uk/382 now not to https://www.example.co.uk/princeton-teak-6ft-garden-bench-chinoiserie-bench.html i cleared and 3emptied my cache completely before testing

Comment: oh sorry, test my updated rule now in a new browser.